# totem not running under crontab

Tags: cron, totem

I'm trying to make an alarm clock using `totem` in `crontab` in Ubuntu 14.04. Reason for `totem` is because it seemed the easiest. I did test out the command `totem --replace /home/edward/mornings.pls` and all seemed to work as expected. I proceeded with to add this to the `cron` (note that it says `0 6` but I have set it to a time few minutes from "now"):

`sudo crontab -e`

`0 6 * * * totem --replace /home/edward/mornings.pls`

However, `totem` did not restart the playlist (yes, it was still open). I looked around a bit to try and troubleshoot things. `/var/log/syslog` shows that `CRON` seemed to execute it without problems:

```
Nov 20 06:00:01 compname CRON[24634]: (root) CMD (totem --replace /home/edward/mornings.pls)
```

I tried appending `> /home/edward/mornjobs.txt` to the end of the command to get some output (both `>` and `&>`). The file was empty. Looking some more, it was suggested that I should set the `DISPLAY`:

`0 6 * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 && totem --replace /home/edward/mornings.pls &> /home/edward/mornjobs.txt`

Tried without the `&&`, as `DISPLAY=:0` and `DISPLAY=:0.0`, `export`ed the `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` and still `totem` does not restart the playlist without (visible) error. Even shutting down `totem` doesn't open it anew. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out some programs won't run under root. Do NOT have `sudo` in the `crontab -e` for this particular moment.